# How Can I Select *Only* Direct Descendents?

Tags: playwright

Let's say you have a basic Playwright locator:

```
const locator = page.locator('.foo');
```

Now, you want to get *just* the `<div>` children of that locator ... not the grandchildren, great-grandchildren, etc. ... *just* the direct children.

You might naively try:

```
locator.locator('div');
```

... but that gets grandchildren and other descendants also.  You might also try using the CSS direct descendant selector:

```
locator.locator('>div');
```

... but that *also* gets the grandchildren and other descendants.

Is there any way to get only the immediate/direct children of a locator?

Comment: Can you share an example of what you're trying to select? `locator.locator('>div');` should get immediate children, if I'm not mistaken. Is there a reason not to use `const locator = page.locator('.foo > div');` directly?

Comment: Oh, you're absolutely right, `'>div'` *does* work (for some reason I saw it not work, but it must have been a caching problem or something, because when I tested just now it worked great).  If you care to put "use `>div` dummy" in the form of an answer I'll happily accept it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS selector for targeting only immediate children and not other identical descendants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732130/css-selector-for-targeting-only-immediate-children-and-not-other-identical-desce)

Comment: No, that's not really a duplicate: that question is about CSS selectors in general, this one is about applying them in Playwright.  In fact, the proposed answer (`'>div'`) isn't even a valid CSS selector: it's only meaningful in Playwright.

Comment: The fact that Playwright adds `:scope` seems like a trivial difference. I don't think this warrants a unique question, and in any case, it proceeds from a false premise since you have the solution already, so the issue is failing to execute the correct code or a typo/misunderstanding. In Playwright, selecting like this is potentially an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676) anyway, since CSS selectors are discouraged. There's likely a better way to do whatever you're trying to do, but there's not enough information to usefully answer.

Comment: I'm not a CSS expert, but a bare `>` is supported in Sizzle and most other flavors of CSS, for example: `console.log($("p").find("> b").text())` will work on `<p>a<b>b</b></p>`. I'd still write your original in a single locator so it's standard CSS anyway, in which case, it's an exact dupe and you can optionally adapt it to fit your particular use case.

Comment: @ggorlen no, `>div` is not a valid CSS selector in general, you could try in a browser console `document.querySelector('body').querySelector('>div')` and would receive an error message that ">div' is not a valid selector" (quoted from Firefox)

Comment: @cyberbrain I'm aware of that: "The fact that Playwright adds `:scope` seems like a trivial difference". As I mentioned, Sizzle and most other flavors of CSS beyond vanilla CSS (probably SCSS, untested, definitely LESS) support bare `>`. Anyway, I think the point has been made and missed here--it's not really about whether bare `>` is supported; it's about whether `>` selects children only or operates deeply, and OP confused themselves into thinking it operated deeply by not running the right code or something like that.

Comment: Had OP created a complete, runnable [mcve] with a simple snippet (I've prompted them for the same on many numerous posts without luck), they'd probably have seen that `>` works as they expect. If it's not a dupe, then it's "no longer reproducible".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually nailed it. '>div' will get you direct descendants.

```
locator.locator('>div');
```

For reference, here's the docs for [`locator.locator()`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-locator).